# Is the War of the Worlds the first story with intelligent but completely uncommunicative aliens?

Tags: aliens, war-of-the-worlds

There is no question that the Martians are intelligent, for this is in the very beginning of the story -- they are as much above humans as humans above microorganisms or at least the Martians have no more regard for human intellect than we do for that of single-celled creatures.

I don't know if there is an equivalent scene in the novel to the one in the 1953 movie where the three men wave the white flag and attempt to talk to the Martians, but that scene shows that Martians have just zero interest in humans as individuals. (In Spielberg's version, the creatures who investigate the basement actually do appear as if they would be interested in communication as they look with curiosity upon the photograph of humans.)

The disintegration of the trio is consistent with the Martians probably being aware of human intelligence and technology -- they have no need to find out anything more, they have plans for the humans that do not require talking to them. The trio might be dangerous if the Martians decide they want to get out and take a walk or maybe they just want to try out the weapon and/or they are just terrible creatures who might enjoy killing humans.

You can have unintelligent aliens or aliens incapable of communication but it seems to me in other stories, that the aliens are intelligent means there will be some sort of conversation -- otherwise, their intelligence is not a very interesting aspect of the story.

I think Wells' intro implies that the Martians have no curiosity about humans because of their superiority; they don't expect to learn anything from them and they do not need to persuade them of anything either -- they will take everything they want by force.

So my question is, is WOTW the first story with completely uncommunicative but intelligent aliens?

Comment: I imagine that WotW is indeed the first story with non-communicative aliens - as well as the first with wholly inhuman aliens. However, it is hard to prove a negative.

Comment: Another possibility isa J.-H. Rosny's novella *Les Xipéhuz", where prehistoric humans battle stone-like, intelligent beings that may or may not be extraterrestrial. They are described (in another source) as being uncommunicative. However, it is unclear if they are really aliens or just of another evolutionary path. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Xipéhuz

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen: aliens or not, they seem to be superior in intelligence or at least technology and perhaps for the same reasons as wells' martians do not speak to men. firstly, not easy especially if your physiology is different and secondly, why would they. human hunters i do not think chat with prey -- they avoid making sounds unless they need to scare the animal, like a bear, and such noise is never an attempt to impart information beyond -- get away, i am here. humans avoid thinking of prey animals as reasoning beasts because it is easier to kill them if you do not believe they are.